# WP simple shopping cart

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart

I'm looking for a very simple WP shopping cart. A single category with a few products. No checkout needed, the user just fills out the address information, hits "Finish order" and a mail containing these information will be delivered to me.

Any tips?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I'm afraid this is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Check out the WP plugin repository though; Googling `WP Simple Shopping cart` should give results, as well.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-simple-paypal-shopping-cart/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the requirements you've posted, I'd choose [WP Order Cart](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-order-cart/).